# varchar datatype doesnt show result for long entries

Tags: php, sql, mysql

i am developing an application to monitor ip adress activity. I am using a LAMP stack on Ubuntu 12.04. In the mysql database, i created a table with 2 columns , ip and mac, both have datatype varchar. i put some data into the table and when i use select * from table, this is the result

```
 ip                    mac
 1                       2
1.10.0.0.43       00 19 78 D3 R5 ED
8.9                 32.22
```

The middle row is how i expect the entries that will come from a switch to look like.The first and 3rd i put them for testing purposes.

I have written a php code to do the matching and retrieval and it is as follows

```
<?php

    $var = $_REQUEST['IP'];    
    echo $var;

    mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "mysql" ) or die("Unable to connect to the database");
    mysql_select_db( "syslog" );

    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT ip,mac FROM arp_table where ip=$var"  );

    $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result );

    print_r( $row );

?>
```

when i enter 1 on the form ,the result is ok, in the form of `1 Array([0]=>1[1]=>2)` and when i enter 8.9, the output is ok as well. But when i enter 1.10.0.0.43, the output is only the echo of the variable, no array is retrieved. Anyone with an idea of why this is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are not using quotes around `$var`. When using strings in SQL they need to be quoted such as:

```
SELECT ip,mac FROM arp_table where ip='$var';
```

If they are not quoted then your value will be interpreted by MySQL and will be automatically converted to (for example) `integer` because the value looks like an integer `1` / `2` ... etc..

Answer (score 0):

use quotes around $var to declare the varchar datatyp

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT ip,mac FROM arp_table where ip='".$var."'"  );
```

it worked with the other two values, because they are interpreted as integer or float datatypes